# Minimum value of $|z|$ if $|z-(4+3i)|=3$

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

By triangle inequality, we have that

$$|z+(-4-3i)| \leq |z|+|4+3i| $$

So $$3 \leq |z| +5 $$

That means $$ -2 \leq |z| $$

But geometry says it should be $+2$ .

What am I doing wrong? How can I prove it without geometry of the locus ?

Comment: Your inequality is true, but it isn't strong enough. We can do the same like this: $3  = |4 + 3i - z | \geq |3 + 4i| - |z| \implies |z| \geq 2.$

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your conclusion that $|z|\ge-2$. But this does not imply that $|z|$ can really attain the value $-2$. As $|z|$ is always non-negative. $|z|\ge-2$ cannot be wrong. Just not enough to find the minimum with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, this means that the distance between $z$ and $4+3i$ is $3$ and $|z|$ is the distance form $z$ to the origin. So, our minimum value would like on the line between the origin and $4 + 3i$ that is $3$ units away form $4+ 3i$. We easily see that this is $5 - 3 = 2$.

Comment: Yes . But how can I prove it without geometry? Thank you

Comment: I made a comment in the original post you made :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't want geometry, solving analytically is not so frightening.

You want to find the minimum of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ while $g(x,y)=(x-4)^2+(y-3)^2-9=0$.

To get this this we need $\vec{\operatorname{grad}f}=\begin{pmatrix}2x\\ 2y\end{pmatrix} \propto \vec{\operatorname{grad}g}=\begin{pmatrix}2x-8\\ 2y-6\end{pmatrix}$

This is $\begin{cases} x-4 = ax \\ y-3=ay\end{cases}\implies \displaystyle g(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)a^2-9=\frac{25a^2}{(1-a)^2}-9=0$

Solving for $a$ gives $a=\frac 38,\ -\frac 32$.

$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac 9{a^2}=64$ or $4$ so $|z_{max}|=8$ and $|z_{min}|=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Inequalities Among Complex Numbers](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml), $$|z+w|\le|z|+|w|\implies|z+(-4-3i)|\le|z|+|-4-3i|=|z|+5$$

So, we need $3\le|z|+5\iff|z|\ge3-5=-2$ which is always true

and $$||z|-|w||\le|z-w|\implies||z|-5|\le|z-(4+3i)|$$

If $|z|\ge5,3\ge|z|-5\iff|z|\le3+5$

Else $|z|<5\implies5-|z|\le3\iff|z|\ge5-3$